# Avro message serialized within flink application fails to deserialize outside flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have a generated Avro class (i.e. extends SpecificRecordBase) which happens to be named PeopleTransformation.  I'm not using a schema registry and am hoping not to have to use one to solve this problem.

I am explicitly serializing constructed instances of PeopleTransformation in my flink application using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

The code is as follows (I recognise there there should be a try catch finally but that's a separate issue)

```
public static byte[] serialize(PeopleTransformation record) throws IOException {
  DatumWriter<PeopleTransformation> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<PeopleTransformation>(record.getSchema());
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
  writer.write(record, encoder);
  encoder.flush();
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
  return out.toByteArray();
}
```

I send the resulting byte array out through my FlinkKafkaProducer, via Kafka, to a Kafka consumer (separate JVM, non-Flink simple Java application) where I attempt to deserialize it using the same avro library.

```
public static <T extends SpecificRecordBase> T deserializeRecord(byte[] bytes, Class<T> avroClass)
  throws IOException {
  SpecificDatumReader<T> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(avroClass);
  return reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null));
}
```

This results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 40
at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:402)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
......
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
```

After investigation I've noted that my flink application contains the following dependency (which seems to be necessary even though my application makes no explicit use of its classes):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and that that package introduces an org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroInfoType class (https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.14.2/flink-formats/flink-avro/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/formats/avro/typeutils/AvroTypeInfo.java#L82-L85)
which, if I'm understanding correctly, seems to be used to automatically convert each CharSequence in a schema to a Utf8. The javadoc for this class (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/formats/avro/typeutils/AvroTypeInfo.html)
says:

"Special type information to generate a special AvroTypeInfo for Avro POJOs
(implementing SpecificRecordBase, the typed Avro POJOs). Proceeding: It
uses a regular pojo type analysis and replaces all
GenericType with a GenericType<avro.Utf8>. All other types
used by Avro are standard Java types. Only strings are represented as
CharSequence fields and represented as Utf8 classes at runtime.
CharSequence is not comparable. To make them nicely usable with field
expressions, we replace them here by generic type infos containing Utf8
classes (which are comparable)".

Could the above substitution explain the incompatibility I'm seeing?  If not is there any other explanation?  (I've tried removing the flink-avro dependency from my flink application but I then
get a missing class exception with respect to AvroTypeInfo)?

Any explanation or insight would be very welcome. Note that in production use the messages will be consumed by third-party applications into which it would be difficult to introduce any Flink specifics.

Comment: Did you consider using an `AvroSerializationSchema<PeopleTransformation>` instead of implementing your own serializer?

Comment: One more thing to check, seems that `flink-avro` depends on `org.apache.avro` in version `1.10.0`, so You may want to double check if the versions used are actually compatible.